# Andorid BitmapRegionDecoder(For cutting large images into rectangular pieces) code not working properly

Tags: android, android-bitmap

i need help to understand BitmapRegionDecoder and how to use. I am not able to figure out how to calculate the x and y of screen to cut the image to make grid.  I want to cut a specific grid on image click. how can i do it. This image is large and normally the image size vary based on different situation.

PFB code which is not working and throwing  Failed to decode region exception:

```
 try {
            InputStream in = null;
            URL url = new URL("http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/img_png/pnglogo-blk.png");
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            try
            {
               in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            BitmapRegionDecoder regionDecoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(in, false);
            Bitmap img = regionDecoder.decodeRegion(new Rect(100,100,100,100), options);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(img);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/img_png/pnglogo-blk.png");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but i need BitmapRegionDecoder to cut the images into rectangular pieces